# How to switch app’s UI and the Storybook UI

Tags: react-native, storybook

I am setting up Storybook to develop components in my app, what is the best way to switch between UI's?

Currently I am replacing my app entry with :

```
export default from './storybook';
```

How do I remove this when in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `yarn add react-native-config`, then `pod install`
- If you're developing for Android, add an import line as described [here](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#extra-step-for-android)
- In your project root, create an .env file
- Any environment variables you add to .env
  can be accessed as Config.YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE

`Now, add the environment variable LOAD_STORYBOOK=true to .env.`

In App.tsx, change your code like below so that Storybook is rendered conditionally.

```
import StorybookUI from './storybook'
import Config from 'react-native-config'

const App = () => {
  return (
    // Your actual app
  )
}

export default Config.LOAD_STORYBOOK === 'true' ? StorybookUI : App
```